# Using tensorboard with a DQN algorithm

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, reinforcement-learning, dqn

For reinforcement learning I have read that tensorboard isn't ideal since it gives the input of per episode and/or step. Since in reinforcement learning there are thousands of steps, it doesn't give us an overview of the content. I saw this modified tensorboard class here: https://pythonprogramming.net/deep-q-learning-dqn-reinforcement-learning-python-tutorial/

the class:

```
class ModifiedTensorBoard(TensorBoard):
    # Overriding init to set initial step and writer (we want one log file for all .fit() calls)
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.step = 1
        self.writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(self.log_dir)
        self._log_write_dir = os.path.join(self.log_dir, name)

    # Overriding this method to stop creating default log writer
    def set_model(self, model):
        pass

    # Overrided, saves logs with our step number
    # (otherwise every .fit() will start writing from 0th step)
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.update_stats(**logs)

    # Overrided
    # We train for one batch only, no need to save anything at epoch end
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        pass

    # Overrided, so won't close writer
    def on_train_end(self, _):
        pass

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        pass

    # Custom method for saving own metrics
    # Creates writer, writes custom metrics and closes writer
    def update_stats(self, **stats):
        self._write_logs(stats, self.step)

    def _write_logs(self, logs, index):
        with self.writer.as_default():
            for name, value in logs.items():
                tf.summary.scalar(name, value, step=index)
                self.step += 1
                self.writer.flush()
```

and I would like to make it work with this layer:

```
n_actions = env.action_space.n
input_dim = env.observation_space.n
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, input_dim = input_dim , activation = 'relu'))#32
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))#10
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_actions, activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss = 'mse')
```

But I have yet to get it to work. Anyone who has worked with tensorboard before, do you know how to setup this up? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use tensorboard always during training of RL algorithms without any modified code like above.
Simply initiate your writer:

```
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir=log_folder)
```

Start your code with:

```
with writer.as_default():
    ... do everythng indented inside here
```

And e.g. if you want to save you reward or the weights of your first layer to tensorboard every 100 steps just do:

```
if step % 100 = 0:
    tf.summary.scalar(name="reward", data=reward, step=step)
    dqn_variable = model.trainable_variables
    tf.summary.histogram(name="dqn_variables", data=tf.convert_to_tensor(dqn_variable[0]), step=step)
    writer.flush()
```

That should do the trick :)